# Postgres SQL on AWS RDS how to grant permission for schema, select on tables to user

Tags: postgresql, permissions

I have logged in as superuser and created a readonly user.

When I run grant command, it says that schema does not exists

I am logging in as root:

```
sql -h myhost_name -U root -d postgres -W

grant usage on schema autorsid to readonly ;
ERROR:  schema "autorsid" does not exist
```

while schema does exists  but schema owner is not root.

Isn't when you are superuser, we should be able to grant permissions for all database/schema/tables etc.

Comment: Does the schema exist in the "postgres" database, or does it exist in some other database in the same cluster?  Not even superusers can cross database boundaries.

Answer (score 0):

Try grant with double quotes around schema name:

grant usage on schema "autorsid" to readonly ;

Comment: still same thing. As a root ( which is superuser on AWS postgres), db_autorsid=> grant usage on schema "autorsid" to readonly ;
ERROR:  permission denied for schema autorsid
db_autorsid=>

Comment: I can grant permission when I connect to user who owns schema ( schema owner) but not when I am connected to superuser. So what exactly is superuser in Postgres, I need something to sqlplus / as sysdba or sys user in oracle which can grant all kind of priviliges.